# google apps script ui show modal requires drive access

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two google accounts. #user1 and #user2.

Using #user1 I create simple Apps Script add-on:

```
function onInit() {
  const section = CardService.newCardSection();
  section.addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText("Open HTML")
        .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("openHtml")));

  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .setName("Cart name")
        .addSection(section)
        .build();
}

function openHtml() {
    const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h1>Enter feedback</h1>");
    DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Modal title");
}
```

When I click on 'Open HTML' button, inside modal dialog I get 'You need access' form. Like [this one](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-forums-api/attachment/thread-49674397-13033735051982850501.jpg)

But in this form I detected as #user2.
If I logout #user2, then modal opens correct.

May be I need to setup some setting, or maybe this is bug?

Here is my appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Kiev",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Test",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/people_black_24dp.png",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#2772ed"
      },
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onInit"
      }
    },
    "docs": {},
    "sheets": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: If you wish to logon as two different google user accounts it's best to do it using two different browsers.

Comment: I don't say that I want. Google allows me to do this.

Comment: In one document, you always use only one account. And the problem is that in modal, app think that I logged in as second user.

Answer (score 2):

### It's a bug indeed

Issue with multiple sign-ins are very well known, and you can find several related filed issues on Google's Issue Tracker:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/186665176
- https://issuetracker.google.com/175707203
- https://issuetracker.google.com/171364500
- https://issuetracker.google.com/72798638
- https://issuetracker.google.com/69270374
- https://issuetracker.google.com/72798634

Unfortunately until this issue is fixed your best bet is to avoid being signed in with multiple accounts into the same browser session.

Comment: I just noticed even when I'm signed in with multiple accounts in separate Chrome profiles this bug rears its ugly head x_x.